Is there a way to use the main scrollbar for a popup?
Title: Use main scrollbar to control popup scroll, freeze body background scroll without popup scrollbar
Question:
I'm trying to implement a popup/modal on my website that only uses the main scrollbar of the page for scrolling, without having a separate scrollbar inside the popup. When the popup is open, I want the background (body) to freeze, so users can only scroll within the popup content using the main page scrollbar. I've tried hiding the popup scrollbar, but it creates a slight stretching effect on the background when opening and closing the popup.
Here’s what I’m aiming for:
Use only the main page scrollbar to scroll through the popup content.
Freeze the background (body) from scrolling when the popup is open.
Prevent any internal popup scrollbar from appearing.
What I’ve Tried:
Hiding the popup scrollbar and controlling overflow behavior, but it causes minor layout shifting on the background when toggling the popup.
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import './DetailsPopup.css';

const DetailsPopup = ({ gameId, onClose }) =\> {
const \[gameDetails, setGameDetails\] = useState(null);
const \[showVideo, setShowVideo\] = useState(false);
const \[fullscreenVideo, setFullscreenVideo\] = useState(null);
const \[isPaused, setIsPaused\] = useState(false);
const \[selectedSeason, setSelectedSeason\] = useState(null);
const videoRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() =\> {
fetch(`/sliderData.json`)
.then((response) =\> response.json())
.then((data) =\> {
const game = data.find((game) =\> game.id === gameId);
setGameDetails(game);
if (game?.seasons?.length \> 0) {
setSelectedSeason(game.seasons\[0\].seasonName);
}
})
.catch((error) =\> console.error('Error fetching game details:', error));
}, \[gameId\]);

const handleOverlayClick = (e) =\> {
if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
onClose();
}
};

const handleEpisodeClick = (videoUrl) =\> {
setFullscreenVideo(videoUrl);
};

const handleCloseFullscreen = () =\> {
setFullscreenVideo(null);
};

const handleVideoClick = () =\> {
if (videoRef.current) {
if (videoRef.current.paused) {
videoRef.current.play();
setIsPaused(false);
} else {
videoRef.current.pause();
setIsPaused(true);
}
}
};

const handleSeasonChange = (event) =\> {
setSelectedSeason(event.target.value);
};

if (!gameDetails) return null;

const episodesToDisplay = selectedSeason
? gameDetails.seasons.find((season) =\> season.seasonName === selectedSeason)?.episodes
: gameDetails.episodes;

return (
\<div className="popup-overlay" onClick={handleOverlayClick}\>
\<div className="popup-modal"\>
\<button className="close-button" onClick={onClose} aria-label="Close popup"\>
×
\</button\>
\<div className="popup-content"\>
\<div className="media-section"\>
{showVideo ? (
\<video
ref={videoRef}
className="popup-video-element"
autoPlay
loop
muted
playsInline
aria-label={`${gameDetails.name} video`}
onClick={handleVideoClick}
\\>
\<source src={gameDetails.videoUrl} type="video/mp4" /\>
\</video\>
) : (
\<img src={gameDetails.imageUrl} alt={`${gameDetails.name} cover`} className="popup-image-element" /\>
)}
{isPaused && \<div className="play-icon"\>►\</div\>}
\</div\>

          <div className="popup-details">
            <h2>{gameDetails.name}</h2>
            <p className="popup-rating">Rating: {gameDetails.rating}</p>
            <p className="popup-description">{gameDetails.description}</p>
          </div>
    
          <div className="season-dropdown">
            <span className="episodes-label">Episodes</span>
            {gameDetails.seasons && gameDetails.seasons.length > 0 && (
              <select
                id="season-select"
                value={selectedSeason || ''}
                onChange={handleSeasonChange}
              >
                {gameDetails.seasons.map((season, index) => (
                  <option key={index} value={season.seasonName}>
                    {season.seasonName}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
            )}
          </div>
    
          <div className="episode-list">
            {episodesToDisplay &&
              episodesToDisplay.map((episode, index) => (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  className="episode-item"
                  onClick={() => handleEpisodeClick(episode.videoUrl)}
                >
                  <p className="episode-name">{episode.episodeName}</p>
                  <video className="episode-video-preview" muted>
                    <source src={episode.videoUrl} type="video/mp4" />
                  </video>
                  <p className="episode-description">{episode.description}</p>
                </div>
              ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      {fullscreenVideo && (
        <div className="fullscreen-video-overlay" onClick={handleCloseFullscreen}>
          <video className="fullscreen-video" controls autoPlay>
            <source src={fullscreenVideo} type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>

);
};

export default DetailsPopup;

/* Overlay to cover the viewport */
.popup-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  align-items: start; /* Center popup vertically */
  justify-content: center; /* Center popup horizontally */
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow-y: auto; /* Allow scrolling on the overlay itself */
  cursor: pointer;
}



/* Modal adjustments */
.popup-modal {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: 20px; /* Optional margin from the top */
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Close Button */
.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99;
}

.close-button:hover {
  color: red;
}


/* Media Styling */


.media-section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; /* To prevent overflow from media elements */
}


.popup-video-element,
.popup-image-element {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /* Ensures the video/image covers the space without stretching */
}

.play-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  pointer-events: none; /* Prevents interfering with the video click */
}

.popup-details{
  padding: 10px;
}


.popup-details h2 {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 1.8rem; /* Responsive font size */
  text-align: center;
}


/* Text Styling */
.popup-rating,
.popup-description {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem; /* Adjust font size */
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Season Dropdown Styling */
.season-dropdown {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Ensures padding doesn’t cause overflow */
}
.episodes-label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}


.season-dropdown select {
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Ensures padding doesn’t cause overflow */
}


.season-dropdown select:focus {
  border-color: #007bff;
  outline: none;
}

.season-dropdown select option {
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Episode List */
.episode-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.episode-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.episode-item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.02);
}

.episode-name {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px 0;
  color: black;
}

.episode-video-preview {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.episode-description {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

/* Fullscreen Video Overlay */
.fullscreen-video-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 2000;
}

.fullscreen-video {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

/* Popup Image */
.popup-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/* Video Container */
.video-container {
  position: relative;
}


/* Media Queries for Responsiveness */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .popup-modal {
    width: 90%; /* Increase width on smaller screens */
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .popup-content h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem; /* Smaller font size on small screens */
  }

  .popup-rating,
  .popup-description {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }

  .season-dropdown select {
    font-size: 0.9rem; /* Adjust font size on smaller screens */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .popup-modal {
    width: 95%; /* Max out the width on very small screens */
  }

  .popup-content h2 {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }

  .popup-rating,
  .popup-description {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }

  .popup-video-element {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 400px; /* Limit the height of video */
  }

  .season-dropdown select {
    font-size: 0.8rem; /* Further reduce font size on very small screens */
  }
}


Is this a good idea to begin with? Your modal is likely to have a fixed height, but the height of the page content might differ. So I would have to move the main scrollbar by totally different amounts to achieve the same amount of scrolling in the modal, depending on how "long" the actual page is - that'd rather be a user experience fail in my book. Plus, you can't get the main page content to "stand still" while scrolling it (at least not without some serious trickery.) [...]

[...] So if anything, I would do this on a different "layer" - like, a modal backdrop with a fixed scroll height that is always the same, regardless of actual page content. If you want to do that - then you need to read the current scroll position of the element you are scrolling, and do the Math to translate that into the corresponding scroll position for the modal, by relating it to both element's actual content heights. Basically a "rule of three" calculation.
